# What's the origin of the quote "You da man, Harry. You da man."?

Tags: dialogue, origin

I'm sure it's from a film, and I'm fairly sure it's sort-of said under the breath, in a respectful manner - for example as though the subject, *Harry* is out of earshot anyway.

(Similar to the bit at the end of *Babe* when Cromwell's all like *"That'll do, pig. That'll do."*)

I'm also nearly 100% sure it's not referring to *Harry Potter* in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [**Armageddon**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/) the character ***Bear*** (Michael Clarke Duncan) [says](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/quotes):

> *Yo, Harry, you're the man.*

after *Harry (Bruce Willis)* detonates the bomb.

[[Watch clip on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV4t7x7686g#t=6m47s)]

Comment: You're totally right. Haha! I actually thought it had something to do with Bruce Willis, but wasn't confident enough to mention it.